# Trouble of hiding Form C#

Tags: c#, forms, hide

Previously what I did is:

```
this.Hide();
Newform a = new Newform();
a.Show();
```

Then problem should solve, but now it is not working.
I tested if i use a button to hide the windows, it worked. But i do not want to show a button on the form.

The form is simply waiting for usb input and proceed to next window. (no button).
This is my code:

```
private void Usbauthentication_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Usbdetected();
    try
    {
    watcher.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(this.WaitForUSBChangeEvent);
    watcher.Query = new WqlEventQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_DeviceChangeEvent WHERE EventType = 2");
    watcher.Start();
    }

    catch (ManagementException a)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(a);
    }
}

public void WaitForUSBChangeEvent(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Usbdetected();
}

public void Usbdetected()
{
    list = conn.Select();
    for (int i = 0; i < drives.Count(); i++)
    {
        drivelist.Add(drives[i].Name.Replace(@"\", ""));
        if (list.Contains(usb.getSerialNumberFromDriveLetter(drivelist[i])))
        {
            store = i;
            this.Hide();
            Login a = new Login();
            a.Show();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you indent your code it can more easily be read by humans.

Comment: You're only displaying the form if the condition is true. Are you 100% sure this condition is returning true?

Comment: Sorry about that, i try to adjust the code many times in order to allow the system accept my code, but seems like it required 4 spaces before posting, i will try again

Comment: @DiegoGoesBauleo Ya the condition is definitely true, because it opened the Login form, but didn't hide the current form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
 var form2 = new Form2();
            form2.Shown += (o, e) => this.Hide();
            form2.Show();
```

You also need to make sure you close the original form when the new form is closed:

```
form2.FormClosed += (o,e) => this.Close();
```

So in all, you need to write:

```
    Newform a = new Newform();
    a.Shown += (o, e) => this.Hide();
    a.FormClosed += (o, e) => this.Close();
    a.Show();
```

Comment: Thank you! it works!
But i have some little question regarding the watcher function, i use the watcher function to monitor if any correct usb is plug into the pc for verification and then open a login page for me. But when it detected the correct usb then it open the login page repeatly (no stop) until i stop the program. Any idea how to stop the watcher to do this?

Comment: I tried watcher.WaitForNextEvent() and it really did open one window but the cursor is constantly spinning while i point to the new window (Seems to be constant loading).

Comment: Before you open the login screen, could you call watcher.Stop()? This should prevent the constant spinning you described.